# Use of as.POSIXct and understanding timezone in time series- R

Tags: r, timezone, lubridate, strptime

I am looking to set x-axis limits on a rather simple time series plot in R.
My plot produces limits that are 6 hours *ahead* of my time zone (plot would start and end at 14:00:00 in the example below).
I am currently in "America/Denver".

My data was previously plotted so that everything was shifted 6 hours *back* but I was able to align that properly on the x-axis, but now the bounds/limits of the x-axis are still a problem.

```
date_format <- function(format = "%b %d - %H:%M") {function(x) format(x, format)}

lims <- as.POSIXct(strptime(c("2021-05-04 08:00:00","2021-05-08 08:00:00"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))

combo_ch1short <- ggplot(data = data_combo_ch1short, aes(x = DateTime, y = Z.kOhm, color = probe.pair.name)) + 
 scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format(), limits = lims, date_breaks = "12 hours") + ...
```

Sorry, pretty new to this. Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Edit:

data_combo_ch1short:

```
Time        probe.pair.name      DateTime              Z.kOhm 
1617890878     ch_1_ch_2         2021-04-12 17:52:32   5228.69
1617890878     ch_1_ch_3         2021-04-12 17:52:32   5031.88
1618251752     ch_1_ch_2         2021-04-12 18:22:32   4089.37
1618251752     ch_1_ch_3         2021-04-12 18:22:32   4231.90    
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `lims` in any timezone by specifying the timezone in `tz` argument.

```
lims <- as.POSIXct(c("2021-05-04 08:00:00","2021-05-08 08:00:00"), tz = 'US/Mountain')
```

Comment: Thank you, Ronak! I have previously tried setting limits:            lims <- as.POSIXct(strptime(c("2021-05-04 08:00:00","2021-05-08 08:00:00"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "America/Denver")), however my axis remained 6 hours ahead for some reason.

Comment: `tz = "America/Denver"` is not a valid value. You can run `OlsonNames()` to get all the valid values for `tz` argument. Using `tz = 'US/Mountain'` does not work?

Comment: Hi, thank you. Yes, I have tried 'US/Mountain' as well, with no success.